# Upload images from gallery or click image from mobile camera meteor android app

Tags: cordova, meteor, camera, android-camera

I am building a meteor mobile app and want to add an option for the users to upload images from gallery. Currently I have an option for the users to click images and post them. Below is my code for users to click images and post them

```
var cameraOptions = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        quality:100,
    };
MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
            if(!error){ //insert in db
            }
});
```

I added sourceType to include the gallery. Its working fine but now I am only able to upload images from gallery and not click via mobile camera. Code is as follows

```
var cameraOptions = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        quality:100,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    };
MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
      if(!error){
      }
});
```

Also as I click on an image from my gallery, it directly uploads it, i.e., images are shown in thumbnails in the gallery. If I click on an image, I would want the image to be shown as a full image first and then upload it.
I have added  **mdg:camera** package and **cordova-plugin-camera@2.4.0** in my app.

I can do the task by including diff buttons for clicking an image and uploading an image but I believe a better solution exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for camera, the sourcetype is Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;

and for gallery, it is Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY

You can use a simple 'if' statements to choose between the two. To edit the image before upload, set 'allowEdit' tag to true in the cameraOptions.